# display the first tab content when page load

Tags: jquery

I made a clickable tab system to show dynamic content and it works fine, however
I am struggling to find the solution making the first tab content displayed and make the first tab activated when page loaded. Any help would be really appreciative!

Here is my javascript and html markup:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

  $('[data-toggle="tabajax"]').click(function(e) {
    var $this = $(this),
        loadurl = $this.attr('href'),
        targ = $this.attr('data-target');

    $.get(loadurl, function(data) {
        $(targ).html(data);
    });

    $this.tab('show');
    return false;
});
  


</script>
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <h2 style="text-align: center;">Powerful Purpose</h2>
    <div class="" style="width:70%;margin:0 auto;">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs tabs-up " id="mainNavTabs" style="text-align: center;">
      <li><a href="about.php" data-target="#aboutus" class="media_node active span" id="aboutus_tab" data-toggle="tabajax" rel="tooltip">About The ADRC</a></li>
      <li><a href="participants.php" data-target="#participants" class="media_node span" id="participants_tab" data-toggle="tabajax" rel="tooltip"> Participants / Researchers</a></li>
      <li><a href="researcher.php" data-target="#researcher" class="media_node span" id="researcher_tab" data-toggle="tabajax" rel="tooltip">Scientists / Researchers</a></li>
       <li><a href="healthcare.php" data-target="#healthcare" class="media_node span" id="healthcare_tab" data-toggle="tabajax" rel="tooltip">Healthcares providers</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="aboutus"> </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="participants"> </div>
        <div class="tab-pane " id="researcher"></div>
        <div class="tab-pane " id="healthcare"></div>
    </div>
  </div><!--/row-->
</div><!--/container-->
```

Beckmann

Answer (score 0):

Trigger a click on the first `tabajax`.

```
  $('[data-toggle="tabajax"]').click(function(e) {
    var $this = $(this),
      loadurl = $this.attr('href'),
      targ = $this.attr('data-target');

    $.get(loadurl, function(data) {
      $(targ).html(data);
    });

    $this.tab('show');
    return false;
  });

  $('[data-toggle="tabajax"]:eq(0)').trigger('click');
```